# Can SSMS convert file to binary

Tags: sql-server

I was wondering if it is possible for SQL Server to convert a file to binary then insert it into a table. I am working in Windows with SSMS but the actual SQL Server is on a Linux machine.
I also have a table(Attachment) with a column that is varbinary(max) (AttachmentBinary)

The statement below is able to find the file, convert it and insert it into the column because the file is located on the Linux machine.

```
insert into Attachment(AttachmentBinary) SELECT AttachmentBinary.BulkColumn FROM Openrowset( Bulk '/opt/Jpg Test.jpg', Single_Blob) as AttachmentBinary
```

I tried the same thing with the file located on Windows but get an error saying the file cannot be found because its not on the Linux side.

```
insert into Attachment(AttachmentBinary) SELECT AttachmentBinary.BulkColumn FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\Jpg Test.jpg', Single_Blob) as AttachmentBinary
```

I was hoping that there was a way to convert the file in Windows even though the SQL Server is on Linux.

Comment: Does the Service account have access to the root of `C` on the host it is installed on? I doubt it, nor should it.

Comment: @Larnu No I don't believe it does.

Comment: Well, that would be why it's not working. Put the file somewhere the service account has access to.

Comment: I put the file in a H: directory and still getting `Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot bulk load. The file "H:\Jpg Test.jpg" does not exist or you don't have file access rights.`

Comment: Does the service account have access? I would, again, suggest not. Put it somewhere the service account has access to, as I stated.

Comment: @Larnu How can I find out where the service account has access to?

Comment: That depends on what account the service is running under. The default account only has access to the Install locations. If you're using a different account, whatever you have configured that domain account to have access to.

Comment: @Larnu The default location is on Linux

Comment: What do you mean the default location is on Linux. You're talking about a install on Windows isn't working, not the one on Linux. SQL Server on Windows can't have a default install on Linux, because it's not on Linux; it's on Windows. Or perhaps you're saying you've installed SQL Server on Linux in a container on Windows? If so, you'd need to mount the Windows path to a location in your Container, and then ensure the `mssql` user or group has access to that path.

Comment: @Larnu Under the Server Properties -> Database Settings -> Default locations is on Linux

Comment: You're not making sense here. If you've installed SQL Server on Windows the path **cannot** be a Linux path. Perhaps you've connected to the Linux host when you should be connecting to the Windows host. That would explain why what you're doing isn't working; you've connected to the wrong host.

Comment: @Larnu The SQL Server is on Linux.

Comment: Then why are you trying to use a Windows path? Linux doesn't use Windows paths. There is your problem. Use the Linux path. Linux doesn't use `C` as the main "root" location it's `/`.

Comment: @Larnu That was my question, is there a workaround within SSMS?

Comment: Not in SSMS.  If you mount an SMB share in Linux it could work.  But generally SSMS cant upload client files to blobs.  Powershell can, just search for examples.

Comment: You can do this in Powershell using either `Invoke-Sqlcmd` or `Invoke-DbaQuery`, you can also do this using a C# script, or using DataGrip Do not mess around trying to get SQL Server access to the file

Comment: You appear to be using SQL Server and SSMS interchangeably here, @e417927 ; they are different things. SMS doesn't run on Linux so you can't be using SSMS on your SSMS host, which is why it seemed that what you were talking about is actually SQL Server. SSMS is just an IDE, SQL Server is running the statements above, not SSMS. Therefore when you run statements it's from the perspective of the instance, not yours. But like the others have said, pushing data into SQL Server isn't SQL Server's task; that's a different tool's. If can pull, sure, but only from where it has access to.